# start date end date validation -Jquery/javascript - kendoUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui, datepicker

could any one have idea about doing the same functionality into KendoUI

```
[fiddle][1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/7/
```

i really dont understand how to convert this jquery functionality into kendo. this is an humble request. would be better some one to come down and help

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Refer this link : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index

Comment: @MaulikBhatt sorry thats not meet my requirement .. kindly check my fiddle . i just want the same in kendo datepicker :(

Comment: Or better this one [API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker)

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you trying to achieve? You want to set a max date on the datePicker, why are there 2 datePickers. What do you want to validate?

Comment: am trying validate end date should not less than start date. this is wat happening in that fiddle example the same thing i want achieve in kendo datepicker. i want disable/fadeout past dates in end date exactly same as fiddle example. to be honest i've not tried anythig so far on kendoui since am new to that

Comment: ok these two links we posted should help you to start. Try it out and ask again when you have something working.`<input id="datepicker" value="10/10/2011" title="datepicker" style="width: 100%" />` for html 
and  `$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();` in your js

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze thanks for providing good point to start
https://dojo.telerik.com/awuYa pls look that link.. from the API i've tried this. but no luck.. where i can the error

Comment: Here you go basic example for what you had in your fiddle: [DojoExample](https://dojo.telerik.com/awuYa/5)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much the same logic as in the fiddle you have linked. When you set start date, you set it's date as limit to the end date, and vice-versa:

```
changeDate = function() {
    if ($(this.element).is("#start")) {
        $("#end").data("kendoDatePicker").setOptions({ min: this.value() });
    }
    else {
        $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker").setOptions({ max: this.value() });
    }
}

...
$("#startdate").kendoDatePicker({ change: changeDate });
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EluKu)

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.MegaMind. You totally save my day